# Why is my thread not spawning properly? C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

This is an abbreviated version of my code. I should clarify that "initializeGrid()" behaves properly, so for brevity's sake, I didn't include it. I am trying to get "threadFunction()" to print the values in args but it doesn't work. Please help!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

int gridSize = 12;

typedef struct threadParameter {
    float * grid;
    int top;
    int bot;
}threadParameter;

void* threadFunction( void* args ) {

    threadParameter *param = (threadParameter*) args;
    printf("%d, %d", param->bot, param->top);
    return 0;

}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    int numProcs = 4;

    pthread_t * threadsArr = malloc(numProcs * sizeof(pthread_t));

    float mainGrid[gridSize][gridSize];
    memset( mainGrid, 0, gridSize*gridSize * sizeof(float) );
    initializeGrid(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, mainGrid);

    threadParameter t = {&mainGrid[0][0], 0, gridSize};
    int ret = pthread_create(&threadsArr[0], 0, threadFunction, (void*)&t);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main()` function returns immediately after calling `pthread_create()`.

When `main()` returns, the process exits and is terminated, along with every thread spawned.

You need to add a `pthread_join()` call to wait for the thread to terminate.  Per the [`pthread_join()` POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html):

> The `pthread_join()` function shall suspend execution of the calling
>   thread until the target `thread` terminates

Like this:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    int numProcs = 4;

    pthread_t * threadsArr = malloc(numProcs * sizeof(pthread_t));

    float mainGrid[gridSize][gridSize];
    memset( mainGrid, 0, gridSize*gridSize * sizeof(float) );
    initializeGrid(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, mainGrid);

    threadParameter t = {&mainGrid[0][0], 0, gridSize};
    int ret = pthread_create(&threadsArr[0], 0, threadFunction, (void*)&t);

    pthread_join( threadsArr[0], NULL );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Andrew Henle! That is exactly the problem. Thank you for your rapid and detailed response!

Comment: Another way to solve that problem would be to do a `pthread_exit` instead of an implicit return from `main`. This keeps the process alive and lets all other threads terminate as they chose.